# Error with babel-polyfill and webpack

Tags: webpack, babeljs, babel-polyfill

I am following along a tutorial from Udemy, and we've just downloaded babel.
Everything was working fine until I downloaded babel-polyfill and tried to integrate it.

Currently this is my webpack and babelrc files: 
[Webpack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lk3U7.jpg) &
[Babel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJjlh.jpg)
and this is what the error looks like on the command line:
[Command Line Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVz6I.jpg).

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance for all your help!

Answer (score 14):

The key error there is `Cannot resolve babel-polyfill in...`

This means webpack isn't able to find that module in your `node_modules` folder. Check to make sure it's there in `node_modules/babel-polyfill` and if not install it with `npm install --save babel-polyfill`.

If it's there and you still get this error, there are a few possible reasons.

Make sure the permissions on the files/folders are ok.
Check that you don't have any `NODE_PATH` env var set or there's no `modulesDirectory` setting in your `webpack.config.js` set that would cause webpack to look in the wrong directory.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. It looks like babel-polyfill is in the node_modules folder.

I don't exactly know know what you mean by "Check that you don't have any NODE_PATH env var set" but there is no modulesDirectory setting in my webpack config. Unfortunately it is still not working.

Comment: You're gonna have to share the code at this point for someone to figure it out. Post it on Github.

Comment: For those who are struggling with it even though you did everything well. In my case, I installed global and local npm at the same time so I removed local one and it works well. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out. Looks like I was misspelling 'polyfill' in my webpack configuration.
D'oh!